# Invalid argument when saving pickle file

Tags: python

I am trying to save my machine learning model into a pickle file:

```py
rf_pickle_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"penguin_ml\random_forest_penguin.pickle")
rf_pickle = open(rf_pickle_path, "wb")
pickle.dump(rfc, rf_pickle)
rf_pickle.close()
```

But I got the error below:

```
File "c:\Python_Sync\penguin_ml\penguins_ml.py", line 39, in <module>
    rf_pickle = open(rf_pickle_path, "wb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Python_Sync\\penguin_ml\random_forest_penguin.pickle'
```

Not sure why? Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to double up the backslashes in the path, otherwise they are read as escape characters and `\r` is a special character.

Comment: ok, thanks, the issue is \r with \random. so I use \\random then it is ok. Thanks for helping

Comment: That is not really a duplicate - if you already know python/general string-handling and the concept of escape characters well enough, than you can indeed solve this error with the linked question. But if you know all that you probably don't need the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

`rf_pickle_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"penguin_ml\random_forest_penguin.pickle")`

should read like this:

`rf_pickle_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"penguin_ml\\random_forest_penguin.pickle")`

`\` is an escape character so when you wrote `"penguin_ml\\random_forest_penguin.pickle"` with a single backslash you told the compiler to insert a carriage return (`\r`) in the string and carriage returns are not valid in a windows path. an alternative would be to use Pathlib and make it platform agnostic (work on windos and posix systems:

```py
from pathlib import Path
rf_pickle_path=Path.absolute().joinPath("penguin_ml/random_forest_penguin.pickle")
rf_pickle = open(rf_pickle_path, "wb")
```

In general I would recommend you use `pathlib` over the `os` module as `pathlib` allows you to make portable paths which work on all platforms.

Comment: Stackoverflow really doesn't need another question trying to answer what backslash escape characters are - for something this trivial, please help users by providing a link to a relevant answer, or vote to close the question with it. Sometimes it's hard to find the answer, in this case the only hard part is picking one from the 100s of times this has already been answered.

Comment: I get you on that but my answer also suggests using pathlib Paths.

Comment: That's fair I suppose, although you would do readers a favour by pointing out that focus in the answer as well. However, if you have something to add to a question that isn't really present in the linked duplicate, it's often the best idea to post the alternative solution there, even if it wasn't asked for explicitly. More questions will be pointed there and your answer can help both the original asked and future ones. Typically, adding an answer to the canonical question and adding a comment to the duplicate referring to the specific answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already explains what is going on with `\` being an escape-character so I won't repeat that, but here are two other solutions to your problem of working with windows-paths in python.

No. 1 is to use a **python-feature called [raw strings](https://realpython.com/python-raw-strings/)**:
You can write a string as `r"C:\Users\whatever"`, the 'r' makes it a 'raw string', meaning that you don't intend `\` to be an escape-character but a literal backslash. When using it to work with windows-paths, be aware of the surprising caveat [that raw-strings cant end with a backslash](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash).

No. 2 is to just **not use backslashes for paths**:
Windows can handle forward slashes just fine, things like `os.chdir("C:/Users/name")` just work. In fact, most apis of most languages/applications/frameworks will do the right thing if you give them forward slashes. Even windows powershell and the original cmd which is dated in a few ways work correctly if you execute things like `chdir C:/Users/name`.

Comment: Stackoverflow really doesn't need another question trying to answer what backslash escape characters are - for something this trivial, please help users by providing a link to a relevant answer, or vote to close the question with it. Sometimes it's hard to find the answer, in this case the only hard part is picking one from the 100s of times this has already been answered.